# Use ACF field selection to update another ACF field in the backend

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a “user” field.

The next field is an empty number field.

When I select a user in the first field I would like to grab a value, in this case ‘user_height’, from that users meta data, and populate the next field with it.

I can get that data on the post using this php…

```
$userdata = get_field('client-programme');
$userid = $userdata['ID'];
$height = get_user_meta( $userid, 'user_height', 'true' );
```

…but is there any way of pushing that data into a field on the backend, as soon as the user is selected (and updated when user field is changed)?

Would I have to use some javascript?

Comment: you can use onchange event in the jquery and get the changed value and get the meta using AJAX and populate in the next empty field.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes sense, but now I realise I don't think its possible, as the ACF user select only shows the username on the front end and not the ID, which I think I need to grab the meta data